# MySQL with Rails driving me with local install

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a setting somewhere in rails 4.2.5 makes it try to login without a password to test and dev databases.

Issue I am facing is following I cannot run rake db:migrate, rake db:create etc. command. I always get error not using password. Its not that it is wrong password its just that rails is not using the password provided. See below.

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'sharetribe'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

When I got to check database.yml password is actually correct. I also tested this by running login into the database from the console using same user and password. I also tried dropping the database and creating it again. Here is my database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: sharetribe_development
    encoding: utf8
    username: sharetribe
    password: ***********
    host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
# The example has user root for tests to work with Travis CI
test: &test
    adapter: mysql2
    database: sharetribe_test
    encoding: utf8
    username: root
    password: **********
    host: localhost

staging:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: sharetribe_staging
    encoding: utf8
    username: sharetribe
    password: *********
    host: localhost

production:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: sharetribe_production
    encoding: utf8
    username: sharetribe
    password: ***********
    host: localhost
#    socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Here is mysql command line output.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+------------------------+
| Database               |
+------------------------+
| information_schema     |
| mysql                  |
| performance_schema     |
| sharetribe_development |
| sharetribe_production  |
| sharetribe_test        |
| sys                    |
+------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'sharetribe'@'localhost';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for sharetribe@localhost                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'sharetribe'@'localhost'                                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sharetribe_development`.* TO 'sharetribe'@'localhost' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sharetribe_test`.* TO 'sharetribe'@'localhost'        |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sharetribe_production`.* TO 'sharetribe'@'localhost'  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your password has some special characters not escaped correctly in the database.yml. Have you trying to change them to more simple?

Comment: Ok there is something else going one here. Changing database did not work but I did notice something really strange while rake db:migrate gives error Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'sharetribe'@'localhost' (using password: NO) RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate actually gives me rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) its definitely not even using database.yml file information.

Comment: So besides database.yml this project included database.example.yml and it seems Rails is not that picky deleting it and rake starts running. I now have a new error but that is another story.